# Error resolve in connecting mongoose to node

Tags: node.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
main().catch(err => console.log(err));
 async function main() {
```

await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
}

error

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:807:32)    at E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:340:10
at E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at promiseOrCallback (E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)    
at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1140:10)
at Mongoose.connect (E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:339:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\index.js:4:10)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10) {
```

reason: TopologyDescription {
type: 'Unknown',
servers: Map(1) {
'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
_hostAddress: HostAddress { isIPv6: false, host: 'localhost', port: 27017 },
address: 'localhost:27017',
type: 'Unknown',
hosts: [],
passives: [],
arbiters: [],
tags: {},
minWireVersion: 0,
maxWireVersion: 0,
roundTripTime: -1,
lastUpdateTime: 194037884,
lastWriteDate: 0,
error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
at connectionFailureError (E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:381:20)
at Socket. (E:\Web Dev\Backend\New folder\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:301:22)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:640:26)
at Socket.emit (node:events:520:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
}
},
stale: false,
compatible: true,

}
}

Comment: try to connect using mongo client from shell

Comment: SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this does the trick:

```js
async function main () {
  const connectionOptions = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
   }
   
   try {
    await moongose.connect(/*Your URL*/,connectionOptions)
    console.log(`Connected to MongoDB`)
   } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Couldn't connect: ${err}`)
   }
}
```

Comment: invalid shorthand property

Comment: There was a mismatch in the connectionOptions object sorry (`'='` instead of  `':'`)